# Lucene: upgrade old project

Tags: java, class, lucene

I've built a project long time ago using Lucene 4.6. Now currently want to upgrade to 7.3.

This project has three files with one class each (with the same name as the file): Main, Indexer, Search.

The Main class carries the logic and calls the Indexer and Search in a procedural way.

I'm getting a problem while searching.

Inside of *Main.java* i have defined the place with the data directory and where the index is going to be and give Search term:

```
File dataDirectory = new File("C:\\datalocation");
File indexDirectory = new File("C:\\indexlocation");
(...)
Search.searchThis(indexDirectory,"Maven");
```

Inside of *Search.java*:

```
package code;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;

public class Search {

    static void searchThis(File indexDirectory, String findme)
            throws IOException, ParseException {

        Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(indexDirectory);
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        IndexReader indexreader = IndexReader.open(directory);
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexreader);

        QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("contents",
                new StandardAnalyzer());
        Query query = parser.parse(findme);
        TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search(query, 10);

        ScoreDoc[] hits = topDocs.scoreDocs;
        for (int i = 0; i < hits.length; i++) {

            int docId = hits[i].doc;

            Document d = searcher.doc(docId);

            System.out.println(d.get("path"));

        }

        System.out.println("Found: " + topDocs.totalHits);
    }

}
```

The problems I get are:

1. > The method open(Path) in the type FSDirectory is not applicable for
   >   the arguments (File)
2. > The method open(Directory) is undefined for the type IndexReader

**How can I fix this?**

Changing type of 'indexDirectory' to 'Path' is not an option to consider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 - Convert using [File.toPath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toPath()):

```
File yourFile = indexDirectory;
Path yourPath = yourFile.toPath();
Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(yourPath);
```

2 - Use [DirectoryReader.open](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/DirectoryReader.html#open-org.apache.lucene.store.Directory-):

```
DirectoryReader indexreader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
```